# How do I get the current date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, date

How can I get the current date, and format it like "20/12/2010"?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateString);
```

*[See also.](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatter-examples.html)*

Comment: Instead of 'dd' can you get it to say "Monday", "Tuesday", etc..??

Comment: @Supertecnoboff - everything you can use is referred to in the Apple docs.  For example: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 6):

Break it down.

*How do I get the current date?* See [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

*How do I format a date in a specific format?* See [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method to retrieve the current date and print as a string using Swift on IOS 9

```
    let formatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yy"
    let myStr : String = formatter.string(from:   NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0) as Date)
    print(myStr)
```

**XCode Debug Print**

```
5/6/16
```